# How to get id from Mongoid in Angular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I uses Rails 4 and MongoDB by Mongoid gem.
I have Angular template like this:

```
<ul><li><a href="" ng-click="navNewEmail()">Add a new post</a></li></ul>

<section>
  <h1>Availabe templates: (click to load content)</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="email in data.emails">
      <h3><a href="" ng-click="viewEmail(email._id)">{{ email.subject }}</a> - author: {{ email.user_name }}</h3>
{{ email._id }}
  </div>
</section>
```

How can I get a `id` of my `Email` object?
I have simple `Email` object in MongoDB.
I tried `email._id` but Angular display nothing.

Everything works besides `{{ email._id }}` part.

Log from JavaScript console:

```
$$hashKey   
    "005"

_id     
    Object { $oid="5478774a6a61734d8a000000"}

body        
    "Here is the sample conte...le ble ble. Nice email."

subject     
    "This is first template"

user_name       
    null
```

So `_id` is the object. How can I convert it into string and display in angular template?

I do something like this:

```
  {{ email._id.$oid }}
```

I don't know is it correct but works.

Comment: email.subject works?

Comment: Yes, everything works besides `email._id`.

Comment: Please try to inspect the data.emails using javascript. console.log(data.emails) in the angularjs controller. and post the javascript log messages here.

Comment: then please try {{ email._id.$oid }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can serialize json object in rails side using 'active_model_serializers' gem.

```
gem "active_model_serializers", github: "rails-api/active_model_serializers"
```

and create your own serializer in serializers directory

```
class EmailSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :_id, :body, :subject, :user_name
end
```

then, try to use {{email._id}}

so, I think that active_model_serializers calls object._id.to_s method automatically when it performs serialization.